# Перевести строку "[12, 23]" в массив того же вида

Tags: python

Я могу решить данную проблему путем простого вытаскивания числа из строки с последующим переводом в int и добавления в массив. Но мне просто интересно как можно сделать это короче и проще, есть ли способ?

```
result1 = w1['temp1'] + w1['temp2']
        currentTemp = []
        num2 = ""
        for char in result1:
            if char.isdigit():
                num2 = num2 + char
            else:
                if num2 != '':
                    currentTemp.append(int(num2))
                    num2 = ''
        if num2 != '':
            currentTemp.append(int(num2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С некоторыми допущениями можно так, а вообще способов полно разных:

```
str_list = "[12, 23]"
lst = list(map(int, str_list[1:-1].split(',')))
print(lst)
# [12, 23]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import ast
s = "[12, 23]"
l = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот ещё вариант:

```
import json
s = json.loads("[12, 23]")
```